# CSS file reference doesnt work when specified in head

Tags: html, css

In my html5 web page i am referencing a CSS file in `head` tag as below.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

This seems to not work however if i put same link tag in the `body` it works. Examples online seems to suggest that it be specified in the `head` tag. Please help.

Comment: Path is correct. I found that 
<code>
body{
    background-image: url('../img/creambackground.png'); 
}
</code>
causes images to change if changed but something like 

`.mainHeader nav li{
    float:left;
    display: inline;
}`

doesnt change anything in browser.

Comment: but if i put the <link> in the body it changes! hope thats clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be working because the page has other styles, declared either inline or attached with a link tag, thus overriding this stylesheet.

Try putting all them in the head tag before this link tag referencing `css/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Try an URL starting with forward slash

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

if the "page" is in a folder and css is in another folder, then you'll have to write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

suggested reading:

http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/
http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php